# alight-item with flex inside button tag does not work in google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

The child inside button in google chrome browser always centered.
The `align-items` doesn't work.

However in firefox it works:

```css
.button {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0u3c1gre/1/

[image: Child elements in button in google chrome always centered]